# How can I randomize Wave Texture's Wave Width?

Tags: materials, shaders, color

I'm trying to create a Brown Dwarf / Jupiter look.

[image]

The waves / bands are all relatively evenly sized and the colors are very "black / white / black / white"

Is there a way I can randomize the width / scale of the lines and apply different colors to them within my nodes?

Current node setup:

[image]

Comment: a quick way would be to add colors to your ColorRamp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a Wave Texture as the scale factor for a Noise Texture:

[image: Planet]

You can change the detail or distortion levels of the Wave Texture or the Noise Texture (or both) for interesting effects:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thankyou